# Assigning a Variable to dict.keys() where the dict can be accessed concurrently

Tags: python, dictionary

As Python does not allow you to loop through dictionaries in which their size changes, I was wondering if the same problem would occur if you assigned dict.keys() to a variable in a dictionary that can be accessed concurrently, as while you're assigning it, the keys might change; or is it a snapshot and it works fine?

Comment: You are unable to hash a mutable item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3, `dict.keys()` returns a live *view* of the underlying `dict`'s keys; modifying the underlying `dict` while iterating the `.keys()` would have all the same problems as iterating the `dict` directly. If you need to make a snapshot, just call `tuple()` (or `list()` or whatever) on the `dict` (or if you absolutely must for silly reasons, the `.keys()`), e.g.:

```
for key in tuple(mydict):
    # Safe to mutate mydict here, as long as you don't delete keys you might have snapshotted
```

Comment: Nevermind; just read your full answer - so if I called list on it, it would work fine?

Comment: @Lego490: `copy.copy` doesn't work on key views; converting to a `tuple` will actually shallow copy the keys and render them independent of the original `dict`.

Comment: @Lego490: Yeah, I made `tuple` the preferred solution only because it's (trivially) more efficient, but `list` would work equally well. There's no need to call `.keys()` at all, since `dict`s are already iterables of their keys, so making a view that's an iterable of the keys is redundant. `.keys()` is really only useful for the set-like behaviors, otherwise you can usually use the `dict` itself directly.